# Not able to use overhang due to issue in jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui

I have a website where I have to show a notification whenever user lands on a page. I am using [overhang](https://github.com/paulkr/overHang.js/) for this.

As mentioned on their GitHub page, I am using the following links:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

I am getting the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).selectize is not a function
```

I got rid of the error by removing jquery link and keeping only jquery-ui (I am not sure if this is the right thing to do).

But, in using overhang, I constantly get the error:

```
x.easing[this.easing] is not a function
```

I tried multiple versions of jquery-ui but I am not able to remove the error. I don't understand what I should do?

Also, I have a gem 'jquery-rails' in my Gemfile. Could this be creating a conflict?

Comment: I would get rid of this statical tags and use gems for adding both jquery and jquery-ui. Just check version compatibility. I think that jquery link and jquery-rails conflict could be a reason for your bug, but you need to double check that overhang will work on your jquery version from jquery-rails

Comment: Somehow after much trial, I used this link for jquery-ui: <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
and placed it before using overhang.js
I didn't need jquery. Overhang worked after changing to this setup.